# Why is a cloned repo 10x larger than a fetched repo?

Tags: git

We have a remote repo that has exploded in size (1.4G to 14G). We are trying to work out why this repo has increased in size and fix the problem.

In the process we have noticed a significant difference between git clone and git fetch.

If we clone the repo, the cloned repo is also 14G.

```
git clone <remote>
```

If instead, we init and fetch from the remote, the local repo is back to the expected 1.4G.

```
git init
git remote add origin <remote>
git fetch
```

I think those two sets of commands should be similar if not the same.

This indicates a significant difference between clone and fetch. How are these commands different?

We are looking for ways of determining a fix for the remote.

Note that the remote is on a github enterprise server, so we have limited access to the remote repo.

---

Some additional statistics

```
$ git clone git@$REMOTE/main.git .
Initialized empty Git repository in $HOME/cloned/.git/
remote: Counting objects: 439172, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (238472/238472), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (439172/439172), 13.82 GiB | 19.92 MiB/s, done.
remote: Total 439172 (delta 186192), reused 436323 (delta 183501)
Resolving deltas: 100% (186192/186192), done.
```

---

```
$ git fetch
remote: Counting objects: 246663, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (80057/80057), done.
remote: Total 246663 (delta 159364), reused 238800 (delta 153402)
Receiving objects: 100% (246663/246663), 1.13 GiB | 12.25 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (159364/159364), done.
```

Those are some pretty different numbers.

Comment: Are you only fetching one branch, but cloning many?

Comment: Which branches do you fetch, when you init and fetch?  A `git clone` will set `remote.origin.fetch` to fetch all branches, as will `git remote add ...`, but a manual `git fetch <url> <refspec>` won't.

Comment: I added the commands that were used. `git remote add` was used.

Comment: What is the output of `du -h . .git`? Is `.` much larger than `.git`?

Comment: The sizes of from `du -hs .git`.

Comment: what is the output of `git remote` and `git config remote.origin.fetch` in both repositories?

Comment: Have anybody tried to clean up the repository or by accident forced in new branches?  Sounds like there is a lot of garbage that cannot be collected.

Comment: Indeed. We can clean up a cloned repo, but we are unable to clean up the remote repo. We are looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that `git fetch` will only pull all commits from existing branches and tags reachable by those branches in the origin.

However, a `git clone` will grab all commits reachable by all branches and all existing tags.  That is a subtle difference, but what is most likely causing what you see.

You can test this by running `git tag` in both of your repos and see if they list different tags.

If so, you can do `git fetch --tags origin` in your fetched repo that is only 1.4 gig, it will pull down all of those additional commits.

To 'fix' this, you can remove any tags that show up in your cloned but not in your fetched repo.  Just make sure you really do want to loose that commit history! `git tag -d <tagname>` and `git push :refs/tags/<tagname>` for each unwanted tag.

Comment: We discovered that another remote repo had done `git push --tags`, however, the repo had multiple unrelated remotes (ie multi headed). This pushed tags along with their respective commits to the remote repo. Removing the tags has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between the cloned version and the fetched version should be the checkout.

The fetched one should contain only the `.git` directory, while the cloned one will also have a worktree checked out.

"In theory" `git clone -n` should do exactly the same as your fetch.

Do you maybe have some sparse files or easy compressible files in your repository? In this case gits objects might be considerably smaller than the file in the worktree.

You could verify by comparing the output of the working tree with that of `.git`.

Comment: "in theory". Apparently not in practice. The size is of the .git directory.

Comment: Does `git clone -n` result is a small or large repository?