# git-filter-repo did not filter tags

Tags: gitlab, git-tag, git-filter-repo

I have multiple git repositories on a company gitlab and wanted to clean them up using git-gilter-repo, following the steps from documentation:
https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#DISCUSSION

1. Clone the old/big repo and `git fetch --all` branches and tags
   (Note: it is marked as archive in GitLab to make it read-only).
2. Run `git-filter-repo --analyze --force` and review `path-all-sizes.txt`
3. Create two txt files: `paths_to_keep.txt` and `path_to_delete.txt` specifying which directories I want to keep or delete, including some globs.
   Run `git-filter-repo --paths-from-file path_to_keep.txt` and similar with `--invert-paths` for the paths to delete. Make sure to keep a copy of all the `commit-map` files.
   Re-run `git-filter-repo --analyze` and make sure all large files are gone
4. Add a new remote/origin, pointing to a new and fresh and empty repo,
   then `git push --force --all` to upload all branches

The GitLab documentation mentions additional steps:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/reducing_the_repo_size_using_git.html

5. Run `git push origin --force 'refs/tags/*'` to upload tags
6. Run `git push origin --force 'refs/replace/*'` to let tags point to new hashes
7. Wait 30 minutes
8. Run repository cleanup, using the commit-map files

**First repo**, I followed steps 1-6 and it worked as expected, the size was dramatically decreased and all branches and tags were there, pointing to the new hashes. Success!

**Second repository**, the size was decreased, all branches were created, all fine up to step 4.
But then when I execute step 5, all the large files are attached to the tags again, and the repo is large again. When browsing the tags from the GitLab UI, I can see the large files. After executing step 6, the files are no longer visible, but the repo size is still large.

Anybody have an idea what could have gone wrong in the second case? I understand I could use steps 6-8 to remove the files, but why are they even added in the 2nd repo (but not for the 1st)??

Comment: I also asked for help on the git-filter-repo discussions page: https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/discussions/441

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647495/why-is-a-cloned-repo-10x-larger-than-a-fetched-repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there were several tags pointing to unreachable objects. The solution is to modify step 1. Cloning will grab all branches and tags, including the ones pointing to unreachable objects. Instead, do a git init, then add remote, and `fetch --all` and `fetch --tags`, as outlined in this SO question:
[Why is a cloned repo 10x larger than a fetched repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647495/why-is-a-cloned-repo-10x-larger-than-a-fetched-repo)

After that, execute steps 1-5 of the original question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to decrease the size of a repository on GitLab, I recommend following the GitLab documentation on how to do this: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/reducing_the_repo_size_using_git.html

Two possible steps that may have caused the issue you're talking about.

1. Not running `commit-map` to remove internal references.
2. Not doing a `refs/replace` to replace all the references.

Comment: Thanks, I am pretty sure I did not have to do these steps in my first repo. But I have just rephrased my question to make clear I tried these steps in the second repo, without success.
I think the GitLab documentation assumes by default that you continue using the same repository. But I considered it more safe to use a fresh empty repo.

Comment: when you say you can see the large files when browsing again, do you mean in the UI or locally?

Comment: in the GitLab UI, when I go to Repository, Tags, click on a tag, then Browse files

Comment: that sounds like the internal references haven't been removed. You can try the repo cleanup section by itself to see if that helps

Comment: Thanks for your help! Can you clarify whether these steps are also required if I upload to a new repo where the references never existed?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but you'd still want to make sure the local version of the repository doesn't have reference to older larger files before creating a new project